# Controller not recognizing JWT roles .net core 5

Tags: .net, .net-core, jwt

I have set up authorization and authentication in my .net core app.  I am creating my JWT token just fine and adding in a role:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if(user!=null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            var authClaims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"Employee")
            };
            var authSignKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("*******************"));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: "https://example.com",
                audience: "https://example.com",
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                claims: authClaims,
                signingCredentials: new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(authSignKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
                );
            return Ok(new
            {
                token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                expiration = token.ValidTo
            });
        }
        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

I added the claim type Role and assigned in to "Employee" for now.  In my controller I have this: decoration on the whole controller:

```
 [Authorize(Roles ="Employee")]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
```

I also just put Authorize on the controller, and Authorize(Roles="Employee") on the Get() method I was using.  I can generate the JWT and when I view it at Jwt.io  I see this:

```
 {
  "sub": "test",
  "jti": "f3c204d4-151f-402a-bdf5-6574934d4644",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Employee",
  "exp": 1621968453,
  "iss": "https://example.com",
  "aud": "https://example.com"
}
```

So it is getting encoded.  I can't see what I'm missing, I need to assign Roles to logins to control access to methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the problem and I thought I would share.  I checked the startup.cs file to make sure that the app.UseAuthentication() and app.UseAuthorization() were in the correct order.  They were.  Next I checked for spelling to ensure the role was right.  It was.  Found out that the problem was that the ValidAudience and ValieIssuer in the startup.cs file were different from the token generation in the login controller.  I found it by capturing the return header from the call and found the error.  Switched the token creator in the controller to the correct Issuer/Audience and it works.

I am posting this because a lot of the answers were to check the ordering of in the startup.cs file.  This was different area to check.